# Do "neat" and "tidy" also mean "clean"?

Tags: meaning

On this site, the first two definitions of [**"neat"**](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/neat) and [**"tidy"**](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/tidy_1#:%7E:text=tidy-,adjective,and%20with%20everything%20in%20order) seem to mean the same thing:

> **Neat:**
>
> **1. (about things)** *tidy and **in order**; carefully done or arranged*
>
> **2. (about people)** *liking to keep things tidy and **in order**; looking tidy or doing things in a tidy way*

> **Tidy:**
>
> **1. (about things)** *arranged neatly and with everything **in order***
>
> **2. (about people)** *keeping things neat and **in order***

However, on this site, the word **"clean"** also appears in the first two definitions of [**"neat"**](https://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/neat#:%7E:text=Learner%27s%20definition%20of%20NEAT,neat%20handwriting) and [**"tidy"**](https://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/tidy).

> **Neat:**
>
> **1. (about things)** *not messy : **clean** and **orderly***
>
> **2. (about people)** *liking to keep things very **clean** and **orderly***

> **Tidy:**
>
> **1. (about things)** ***clean** and **organized** : not messy*
>
> **2. (about people)** *keeping things **clean** and **organized***

So, do **"neat"** and **"tidy"** also imply *cleanliness* in addition to *order* and *organization*?

*Thank you in advance!*

Comment: Stuff that often goes together doesn't define that teamwork. A neat house appears clean, that's all. Doesn't make it so.

Comment: A collection of pornography might be neat and tidy, but wouldn't be clean for some definitions of clean. What about a library that hasn't been dusted for a while? A museum of stained clothes or yellowed paintings? Or someone who claims "It may look messy but I know exactly where everything is" - is that neat and/or tidy? Words have complex meanings and there is an exception to every rule (mostly).

Comment: Reasonable question with some evidence of research. The answer should involve aspects of synonymity, hypernymity, overlapping meanings and mutually exclusive meanings so the question is not trivial. Leave open.

Comment: Please attribute links and give actual quotes.

Comment: The definition links are on the blue words for each of them.

Comment: @AlexFrt That's not how we do things here. "This site" means **this** site; links can rot. Please type out the relevant parts of the definitions into your question so that it is self-sufficient and [attribute the quotes](/help/referencing) correctly. Thank you.

Comment: @StuartF *Neat and tidy* would in most people's minds suggest cleanliness as well as good order. The library and museum cases you quote would be unlikely to attract a *neat & tidy* label without further qualification. At least not in the UK. Semantically the composite *neat & tidy* has a sense of its own, perhaps beyond that of the two single words - which both have essentially the same meaning. What would *neat but not tidy* mean - for heavens sake?

Comment: It would be useful to link to where you've crossposted question this on ELL, so that people know that the answer might be there instead of here (and vice versa).

Comment: According to your Britannica link, 'neat' and 'tidy' mean clean, though other dictionaries disagree. You want us to adjudicate?